# What is the Azure API version

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I'm trying to access the result of a GET request provided by Azure, as shown in the example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/azure/dn820159.aspx

My problem is that the `api-version` is a mandatory argument, but I have no idea about what to write inside. I'm a bit lost with the Azure Batch documentation, it doesn't seem to be complete.

I found something in an Azure webpage : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-api-versions/ and the api-version was `api-version=2015-02-28`. However, if I try it in my browser, I have this answer : `"key":"Reason","value":"The specified api version string is invalid"`.

Any idea of what I can put inside the `api-version` parameter ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn878154.aspx)

As the time of this writing

> The version of the Batch API described here is '2016-07-01.3.1', and
>   using that version is recommended where possible.
>   Earlier versions include '2016-02-01.3.0', '2015-12-01.2.1',
>   '2015-11-01.2.1', '2015-06-01.2.0', '2015-03-01.1.1', and
>   '2014-10-01.1.0'.

So try specifying `'2016-07-01.3.1'`

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my problem ! I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes when it will be available. Also, it leaded me to another problem which seems to be that an HTTP header is missing. I'll try to investigate this, but if you have an idea about it, I would be glad to hear it :).